# Why compiler tries to Wide and Box Why not Box and Wide?

Tags: java

When invoking a particular method, I read that Wide and Box is preferred, why not Box and Wide. can anyone explain me why with one small example.

Comment: Without any context, we've got no hope of answering the question. What are "Wide" and "Box"? If you could give a small example of what you believe it means, that would really help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Widening and Boxing are well known terms when it comes to Java.  int to long would be widening, int to Integer would be boxing.  And I feel absolutely ridiculous explaining this to the person with the highest reputation on the site.

Comment: @Jon.. Dont say Jon you dont know Widening and Boxing :D.

Comment: @R. Bemrose - I bet it felt pretty good :)

Comment: @gurukulki: I know what widening conversions and boxing conversions are, but your question as it is makes little sense. Please don't make people *guess* what you mean.

Comment: Not even that old: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128034/why-widening-beats-both-boxing-and-var-args-in-overloading-of-a-method

Comment: @PSpeed: Its different friend. Can you give a common answer to both.

Comment: I'm not sure it's different.  Both questions are asking for why the compiler prefers widening to auto-boxing.  The answers in the other thread (so far) are: 1) because auto-boxing is recent and widening has always been there (ie: backwards compatibility), 2) because widening is more efficient than auto-boxing and so should be preferred.  If you are talking about something else then you need to clarify because to me these questions are identical.

Comment: @PSpeed: this is particularly in combination of wide and box. that is with widening over boxing and var-agrs as an individual. hope it is clear now.

Comment: I think you need to provide some examples (in your question above) of what you mean because it is still not clear to me how this is different than the other question.

Comment: P.S.: And I get that the other question is about method overloading but the reasons to prefer widening to autoboxing are the same, I think.  (The fact that I have to reverse engineer this from this discussion and other answers just to figure out what the original question was is less than fun. ;))  In theory the answer to this question answers the other... and I guess technically the answer to the other does not necessarily answer this one, but I think it does.  Java will try to find the closest single-step conversion possible.  int -> Long is not a single step.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Widening: calling a method with a narrower parameter type.

```
public class Test {
    static void doIt(long l) { }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1;
        doIt(i); // OK: int i is widened to long
    }
}
```

Boxing: calling a method that takes a wrapper type with a primitive argument.

```
public class Test {
    static void doIt(Integer i) { }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1;
        doIt(i); // OK: int i is boxed to Integer
    }
}
```

Widening and then boxing: doesn't work.

```
public class Test {
    static void doIt(Long l) { }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1;
        doIt(i); // FAILS. Cannot widen int to long and then box to Long
    }
}
```

Boxing and then widening: only works if widening to a supertype.

```
public class Test {
    static void doIt(Number n) { }
    static void go(Long l) { }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1;
        doIt(i); // OK. i is boxed to Integer, and Number is a supertype of Integer
        go(i); // FAILS: Long is not a supertype of Integer
    }
}
```

Comment: i think Wide and Box which you have shown works Because you can wide int to long. that's what widening is all about. once you say it can and again you say it cannot.

Comment: Paste the examples in your IDE. The lines I have commented 'FAILS' give compiler errors.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is fairly simple: You can only widen primitives.  Therefore, the compiler must widen before it boxes.

Answer (score 0):

From the SCJP Study Material i can tell you this:

When a method is called the following will be checked in this order and if a match is found the appropriate method will be called:

```
1) Widening (preferred: 1st option to be chosen)
2) Boxing
3) Var args
```

It's just the way it works! Mind the order !