# Java Integer can not be coerced to double. Constructor invocation does coerce

Tags: java

I've just spent some time debugging my code.

What I found was rather strange and I'm hoping somebody could explain to me what is going on.

First of all, this give a compile time error:

```
double x = 5.0;
int y = x;
```

Well yes, because you have to explicitly cast it to a double using `(double)`.

I have an object with following constructors:

```
public class MovesValue {
    private ArrayList<Integer> moves;
    private Double value;

    public MovesValue(Integer move, double value) {
        this.moves = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        moves.add(move);
        this.value = value;
    }

    public MovesValue(ArrayList<Integer> moves, double value) {
        this.moves = moves;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public MovesValue() {
    }

    public MovesValue(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

In my code I was invoking a constructor like this:

```
       int moveToMake = beginMoves;            
       MovesValue rv = new MovesValue(moveToMake);
```

And to my suprise, Java invokes the constructor that takes a double as parameter.

Shouldn't it complain that no suitable constructor was found?

## **EDIT**

I have created the constructor which takes an Integer now as well. However, again to my suprise Java still invokes the constructor that takes a double. Does it have to with the fact it's taking an `Integer` instead of an `int` ?

Okay, I feel silly. IntelliJ did not compile my `MovesValue` for some reason. After restarting it it worked perfectly. So I'm very sorry about this guys!

Comment: I'd imagine it's getting autoboxed to an `Integer`, and then `doubleValue` is called on that object.

Comment: double->int and int->double are treated differently.

Comment: I created a simple demo trying to reproduce the issue that you mention in the edit, but I cannot reproduce the problem: [Java calls the constructor that takes an `int` when I pass an `int`, and the constructor taking `double` when I pass a `double`](http://ideone.com/uIuK34)

Comment: See the edit. I feel stupid now though :(

Comment: [Widening conversions are preferred over boxing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128034/why-widening-beats-both-boxing-and-var-args-in-overloading-of-a-method). Strangely, I couldn't find documentation of this behavior in section 5.3 of the JLS, which should cover this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java has no issues converting `int` to `double` implicitly - the following is perfectly valid without a cast:

```
int x = 5;
double y = x;
```

Your call of `MovesValue`'s constructor succeeds because this is the same kind of conversion that Java invokes when you pass an `int` to a constructor that takes a `double`.

An attempt of passing a `double` to a constructor taking an `int` that would cause a problem at compile time:

```
public MovesValue(int value) {              // <<== Changed the type of value
    this.value = value;
}
...
double moveToMake = beginMoves;            
MovesValue rv = new MovesValue(moveToMake); // <<== This does not compile
```

Comment: I understand clearly now. It makes perfect sense :) However, I'm still confused as to why it invokes the `double` constructor when there is an `int` constructor present.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor that takes only a `double` is the only constructor that matches

```
MovesValue rv = new MovesValue(moveToMake);
```

It is the only constructor with exactly one parameter, and Java will use a [widening primitive  conversion (Section 5.1.2, JLS)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) to convert the `int` passed in, `moveToMake`, to a `double` so it can be passed in.

To get the first constructor `(Integer, double)` to be called, then you must pass a second numeric parameter also.  Then, Java will box the `int` into an `Integer`, and either accept the `double` as a second parameter, or widen an `int`, `float`, `long`, etc. into a `double`.