# Why is the Short method calling the integer method?

Tags: java, overload-resolution

```
public class Yikes {
    public static void go(Long n) {
        System.out.print("Long ");
    }

    public static void go(Short n) {
        System.out.print("Short ");
    }

    public static void go(int n) {
        System.out.print("int ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        short y = 6;
        long z = 7;
        go(y);
        go(z);
    }
}
```

This program is giving the output

```
int Long
```

I thought the output was

```
short Long
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2128062/2775450

Answer (score 16):

The [overload resolution section in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) explains why:

> 1. The first phase ([§15.12.2.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2)) performs overload resolution **without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion**, or the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the second phase.
>
> *This guarantees that any calls that were valid in the Java programming language before Java SE 5.0 are not considered ambiguous as the result of the introduction of variable arity methods, implicit boxing and/or unboxing. However, the declaration of a variable arity method (§8.4.1) can change the method chosen for a given method method invocation expression, because a variable arity method is treated as a fixed arity method in the first phase. For example, declaring `m(Object...)` in a class which already declares `m(Object)` causes `m(Object)` to no longer be chosen for some invocation expressions (such as `m(null))`, as `m(Object[])` is more specific.*
>
> 2. The second phase ([§15.12.2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.3)) performs overload resolution while allowing boxing and unboxing, but still precludes the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the third phase.

In the first phase, the compiler does not include the method `go(Short n)` in its resolution. Instead, it deems `go(int n)` to be an applicable method. This method is applicable because a `short` is widening converted to an `int`.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler is preferring to convert a `short` into an `int` rather than box it into a `Short` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

Instead of

```
public static void go(Short n) {
    System.out.print("Short ");
}
```

try

```
public static void go(short n) {
    System.out.print("Short ");
}
```